# How should I store this set of data into a Mongo Collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following Data Structure

```
{
   "routers": [
   {
      "name": "",
      "ip address": "",
   }
   ],

   "devices": [
   {
      "name": "",
      "mac address": [
         <address>,
         <address>,
         <address>
      ],
   }
   ],

   "connection": [ 
   {
      "source":"<name>",

      "destination":"<name>",  

   }
   ]
}
```

I want to store this in a Mongo Database (in a Java web application). I just need some opinions on how to structure this.

Do I put all of this JSON into one Mongo Collection, named "Environment"?

I want to map the data to Java Objects, do I have three separate Objects "Router","Device" and "Connection" OR do I make one Java object "Environment" and have the three Java objects listed above in that particular object? I'm feeling like this second option is the best.

I'm pretty much looking for some advice on the best way to design this, instead of trying to change it later on.

Not that it matters, but I am going to also be using [Jongo](http://jongo.org/)

EDIT to show potential class:

```
private class Environment {
    private List<Router>;

    private List<Device>;

    private List<Connection>

    ...
}
```

There would be multiple "Environment", essentially what we are building is a configuration management system so there are different "Configurations" of Environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do lots of documents in 1 collection. I find it easier to search that way and easier to write pojo-like code against.

Your data modelling question has been answered before: [Mongodb: multiple collections or one big collection w/ index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314769/mongodb-multiple-collections-or-one-big-collection-w-index)

I would use any of the very many JSON utility libs (e.g. GSON) for Java.

1. Create a pojo class that has all of the fields you require in the data structure:

   ```
   private List<Router> routers;
   ...
   private static class Router {
       private String name;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Create getters/setters if you need to
3. Use your utility to convert to/from, example of a utility class below

   ```
   import com.google.gson.Gson;
   import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

   private static Gson gson = new Gson();
   private static final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

   public static <T> T toPojoObject(String json, Class<T> clazz, Gson aGson) {
       return aGson.fromJson(createJSONObject(json).getAsJsonObject(), clazz);
   }

   public static JsonElement createJSONObject(String json) {
       return parser.parse(json);
   }
   ```

(OK not the most wonderful example of using GSON, but just illustrating the point)

Comment: So with recommending lots of documents in 1 collection, would you wrap all of the objects in the parent "Connection" object and save that as a document?

Comment: No, I wouldn't wrap. I would have 1 document, i.e. class called "Network" (or whatever). Network contains your data structure as per the class I (partially) wrote above. You have lots of Network documents in one collection. Sorry I actually presumed you had more than one "Network" . Is that not the case?

Comment: I edited my original question with a class that I put together representing my initial thought. The "Environment" class encompasses essentially the Network. We may be talking about the same thing here. The idea would be to persist the json version of the Environment class into one Mongo Collection

Comment: Ok I think we're talking about the same thing... Edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Making one java object "environment" and including others in it will be better. e.g I am using JPA based object datastore mapper and in that you can use "@embedded" to embed other objects in that entity if you have all the objects embedded in one entity you can persist all the objects using a single call to database otherwise you have to hit the database thrice for persisting the three objects.