# Does combining data with different keys into a single collection affect query performance?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to log various contact activities into an 'Activities' collection. Email activities will be looked up / updated using the email address (contactId isn't known), but non-email activities will only be able to rely on the contactId as the key (as email isn't necessarily available in that data).

Commingling simplifies the database design, but isn't worth any significant performance hit, as scalability is a concern too.

[Edit for clarification compared to similar question here: [Mongodb: multiple collections or one big collection w/ index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314769/mongodb-multiple-collections-or-one-big-collection-w-index])

Specifically, I'm trying to compare the performance impact of running 2 queries (one for each activity type based on a different key each time) against a single collection vs running the same 2 queries against 2 different collections. Rather than general data modeling concerns, i'm interested in understanding if query performance is significantly impacted when a good portion of the queried data has to be ignored by the db engine due because it lacks the key.

Your thoughts appreciated!

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer since it massively depends on indexing, data read access patterns, and other considerations (could you want to do sharding in the future and more). My suggestion would be: Measure it!

Comment: Not easy to measure since this is in reference to pre-production functionality. When it goes live i expect millions of records, but i can't easily create that much test data. I guess I don't know enough to know about indexing / optimization of mongodb to know what happens when the 2 different key fields are sparse in the same collection. Leaning towards 2 seperate collections to be safe.

Comment: I would also recommend two separate collections if there is no clear reason to keep all documents in the same collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb: multiple collections or one big collection w/ index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314769/mongodb-multiple-collections-or-one-big-collection-w-index)

Comment: My question is more focused on performance implications given that the index will be sparse. Found some good reading here on options: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/. I've already moved in the direction of separate collections to avoid performance concerns. Appreciate all the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Some good considerations mentioned in the comments above...and am erring on the side of safety by going with separate collections since that will be easier to index and manage from a DBA perspective.